# lightning:buttonIcon color change

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I am trying to change color of `iconName="utility:check"` on close of modal popup.I have written CSS also.

**My Icon:**

```
 <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:check" class="icn" variant="bare" onclick="{!c.openapproveModel}" value="{!idf.Base_Invention_Disclosure__c}" alternativeText="Approve Invention Disclosure"/>&nbsp;
```

**My CSS:**

```
.THIS.icn svg{fill : red;}
```

I have tried this also `.THIS.icn.svg{fill : red;}`

Comment: The linked question/answer should give you everything you need to figure out the problem, but if not, please **[edit]** your question to include additional code, and we'll be glad to reopen this question for you.

Comment: not really sure how the suggested link (Show/Hide CSS Ignored When Inside an SLDS Grid Column) answer the question,